# Amy slider how to link images

Tags: java, php, wordpress, slider

I have imported an Amy slider in my website. I want when I click on the picture to link in a custom url my website [click here](http://web1.mabox-ks.come).

I dont have any code and I don't really know what code to enter how to make that option when you click in `image1` link in `url1`  `image2` link `url2`

```
<link>IMAGE<url1>
<link>IMAGE2<url2>
<link>IMAGE3<url3>
<link>IMAG4<url4>
<link>IMAGE5<ur5>
<link>IMAGE6<ur6>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would.

`<a href="http://www.example.com">IMAGE</a>`

Comment: I need to make it when i click on the pic and that option isnt available what custom css do i have to add to make that option